# Do we need tags for zombie or defunct processes?

Tags: discussion, tags

The [zombie-process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zombie-process) has zero watchers and 36 questions in 11 years. Yesterday a new tag [defunct](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defunct) was created for defunct processes (no watchers). I don't see what value these tags add if nobody's watching them and they have so few questions asked each year. Since nobody's watching them, their only utility is in searching, and even then the terms aren't common enough that simple text searches couldn't serve the same purpose.

And even if we do need a tag for defunct processes, should it be [defunct-process](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/defunct-process) instead, similar to the one for zombie processes?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a discussion, I presume my opinion can be worded as part of an answer.

I wholeheartedly support your suggestion. Adding to your objective arguments that :

If the OP has got enough knowledge to realize that their question is significantly *zombie-process* related then they get the knowledge needed in order to answer their own question (or at least to eliminate what, in the question is depending on this). (since what is needed to get even a deep technical understanding of the whole zombie thing would happily fit into half of a A4 page.)
If OP does not get that knowledge, they do not know the word or its meaning in context anyway.

I find tags only useful when categorizing **discrete** & important parts of knowledge that only a few can master in full.

---

On a global perspective, there are indeed far too many tags. Simply consider the incredible number of tags matching zero.0.0 question. Adding to the fact that, when tagging my own questions, I often initially exceed the max number of allowed tags.